# What Heads do not have the attribute NumericFunction, but still give True in NumericQ?

Tags: numerical-value, attributes

The following expressions give `True` in the `NumericQ` test:

```
Map[NumericQ, {Rational[2, 3], Complex[2, 3], 
  Root[1 + 2 #1 + #1^5 &, 1], RootSum[-7 - 3 #1 + #1^5 &, Sin[#1] &]}]

(* Out: {True, True, True, True} *)
```

However the heads `Rational`, `Complex`, `Root` and `RootSum` do not have the attribute `NumericFunction`:

```
Attributes[Root]
(* Out: {NHoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected} *)
```

... but `NumericQ` still returns `True` when applied to them.

Is there a way to obtain a list of all the possible heads `h` of expressions `h[args]` that do *NOT* have the `NumericFunction` attribute, and yet will give `True` in the test `NumericQ[h[args]]`?

Answer (score 4):

Note that `Root` is only considered numeric when its argument does NOT contain any non-numerical parameters. For instance:

```
Root[(# - a) &, 1] 
(* Out: a *)

NumericQ@Root[(# - a) &, 1] 
(* Out: False *)
```

A similar argument applies to `RootSum`, `Rational`, and `Complex`:

```
NumericQ@RootSum[a + # &, Log[#1] &]   (* False *)
NumericQ@Rational[a, 2]                (* False *)
NumericQ@Complex[a, 2]                 (* False *)
```

It seems to me that these examples still fall within the general guideline presented in [the documentation for `NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html), under "Details": "`NumericQ[expr]` gives `True` whenever `N[expr]` would yield an explicit number".

Comment: Yes they do fall within the documentation, what I want to know is the explicit list of ALL the heads that fall within the documentation, I know Root, RootSum, Rational, Complex, are there others? Could new ones appear in future versions of Mathematica? If so, how could they be automatically detected in the code of a Mathematica package?